# Windows 2k3 DHCP server not handling multiple scopes

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp

Here's the scenario. I have a test environment configured with 2 windows 2k3 domain controllers. One of the two is handling DHCP. I've set up 2 scopes in DHCP to handle two separate subnets. On a Linux (RHEL 5) server I have dhcrelay running that is listening on Subnet 192.168.2.0 and forwarding to the DHCP server on 192.168.1.10. I have setup a windows xp machine on the 192.168.2.0 subnet that is requesting DHCP. The dhcrelay on the linux server picks up the request and forwards it to the windows dhcp server. Unfortunately though the windows DHCP server receives the packet (have done packet captures and verified this), it doesn't respond to the DHCP request from the relay.

Is anyone familiar with why the windows dhcp server wouldn't be responding to dhcp requests from the relay agent?

The configuration with the scopes is as basic as it can get due to being a test environment and I'm wanting to verify if windows would be able to work as a dhcp server in the production environment rather than a simple test environment.

Thanks,
Matt.

Comment: Forgive me if this seems dumb, but you didn't spell it out. Did you configure a scope for 192.168.2.x on the DHCP server?

Comment: Yeah, both scopes are configured on the DHCP server.

Comment: Are the subnet masks on the DHCP server's scope and the Relay's NIC configuration the exact same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the DHCP server using as a gateway?  If its not part of the 192.168.2.x subnet (or a persitent route isn't set up), are the DHCP requests just getting forwarded to the DHCP servers gateway and then lost?

Comment: The fact that there is no routing between the two subnets is what's causing the issue. This was found by setting a default gateway on the Windows server and then it started sending dhcp offers. Now onto the next problem.